# Eclipse java Maze Don't work

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

my java applet on eclipe don't work it writes "applet intialized" but doesn't procced to "Applet started" and the applet doesn't start (just blank screen) and also there is no errors in the console window.

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvalc.png

My code is about depth-first maze and the problem is in the genrate() function because when i comment it's call the program runs well

Maze.java :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Maze {

// Direction Variables
public static final int Direction_Up=1;
public static final int Direction_Down=2;
public static final int Direction_Right=3;
public static final int Direction_Left=4;
//
//
int width, height;
int SizeX,SizeY;
public int[] start={0,0},end={3,3};
int offset=2;

boolean[][] WallsVer = { { false,true, false ,false},
        { false,false, false ,false}, { false,false, false ,true}};
boolean[][] WallsHor ={ { true,false, false },
        { true,false, true }, { true,true, true }, { false,true, false}};



public Maze(int width, int height,int sizeX,int sizeY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    SizeX = sizeX;
    SizeY = sizeY;
}

//
public boolean CollisionCheck(int x,int y,int Direction){
    switch(Direction){
    case Direction_Up:
        if(y == 0){
            return false;
        }else if(!WallsVer[y-1][x]){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    case Direction_Down:
        if(y==SizeY-1){
            return false;
        }else if(!WallsVer[y][x]){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    case Direction_Right:
        if(x==SizeX-1){
            return false;
        }else if(!WallsHor[y][x]){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    case Direction_Left:
        if(x == 0){
            return false;
        }else if(!WallsHor[y][x-1]){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void update() {

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //draw border
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0);
    g.drawLine(0, height, width, height);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, height);
    g.drawLine(width, 0, width, height);


    //draw maze
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    for(int j=0;j<SizeX;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<(SizeY-1);i++){
            if(WallsVer[i][j])
                g.drawLine(j*100,(i+1)*100 , (j*100)+100,(i+1)*100 );
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<(SizeX-1);j++){
        for(int i=0;i<SizeY;i++){
            if(WallsHor[i][j])
                g.drawLine((j+1)*100, i*100,(j+1)*100, (i*100)+100);
        }
    }
}

public void generate(){
    // horX = sizeX -1
    // horY = sizeY
    // verX = sizeX
    // verY = sizeY -1

    //set and initialize variables
    int TotalCells=SizeX*SizeY, VistedCells=0;
    int[] CurrentCell = start;
    int[] AvaliableCells = new int[4];
    int AvaliableCellsNum = 0;
    int[][] stack= new int[TotalCells][2];
    int stackPointer = 0;
    boolean[][] map = new boolean[SizeX][SizeY];


    //initialize walls
    for(int j=0;j<SizeX;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<(SizeY-1);i++){
            WallsVer[i][j]= true;
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<(SizeX-1);j++){
        for(int i=0;i<SizeY;i++){
            WallsHor[i][j] = true;
        }
    }
    //initialize map
    for(int j=0;j<(SizeX-1);j++){
        for(int i=0;i<(SizeY-1);i++){
            map[0][0]= false;
        }
    }
    map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]] = true;
    stack[stackPointer] = start;
    VistedCells=1;


    while(VistedCells < TotalCells){
        // test all the walls and enter them in AvaliableCells
        if(CurrentCell[0]!=0 && !map[CurrentCell[0]-1][CurrentCell[1]]){
            AvaliableCells[AvaliableCellsNum] = Direction_Right;
            AvaliableCellsNum++;
        }
        if(CurrentCell[0]!=3 && !map[CurrentCell[0]+1][CurrentCell[1]]){
            AvaliableCells[AvaliableCellsNum] = Direction_Left;
            AvaliableCellsNum++;
        }
        if(CurrentCell[1]!=0 && !map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]-1]){
            AvaliableCells[AvaliableCellsNum] = Direction_Up;
            AvaliableCellsNum++;
        }
        if(CurrentCell[1]!=3 && !map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]+1]){
            AvaliableCells[AvaliableCellsNum] = Direction_Down;
            AvaliableCellsNum++;
        }

        // randomization process
        if(AvaliableCellsNum > 0){
            Random RndGen = new Random(); 
            int RndValue = RndGen.nextInt(AvaliableCellsNum);
            AvaliableCellsNum = 0;
            switch(AvaliableCells[RndValue]){
                case Direction_Up:
                    WallsVer[CurrentCell[1]-1][CurrentCell[0]] = false;
                    CurrentCell[1]--;
                    map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]] = true;
                    stackPointer++;
                    stack[stackPointer] = CurrentCell;
                    VistedCells++;
                    break;
                case Direction_Down:
                    WallsVer[CurrentCell[1]][CurrentCell[0]] = false;
                    CurrentCell[1]++;
                    map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]] = true;
                    stackPointer++;
                    stack[stackPointer] = CurrentCell;
                    VistedCells++;
                    break;
                case Direction_Right:
                    WallsHor[CurrentCell[1]][CurrentCell[0]-1] = false;
                    CurrentCell[0]--;
                    map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]] = true;
                    stackPointer++;
                    stack[stackPointer] = CurrentCell;
                    VistedCells++;
                    break;
                case Direction_Left:
                    WallsHor[CurrentCell[1]][CurrentCell[0]] = false;
                    CurrentCell[0]++;
                    map[CurrentCell[0]][CurrentCell[1]] = true;
                    stackPointer++;
                    stack[stackPointer] = CurrentCell;
                    VistedCells++;
                    break;
            }

        }else{
            stack = popStack(stack,stackPointer);
            CurrentCell = stack[stack.length-1];
        }


    }
    end = CurrentCell;

}

private int[][] popStack(int[][] stack,int newlength){
    int[][] temp = new int[newlength][2];
    for(int i=0;i<newlength;i++){
        temp[i] = stack[i];
     }
    return temp;
}

 //getters and setters
public int getHeight() {
     return height;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
 }
public int getSizeX() {
     return SizeX;
}
public int getSizeY() {
    return SizeY;
} 
public int getStartX() {
    return (start[0]*(width/SizeX))+offset;
}
 public int getStartY() {
    return (start[1]*(height/SizeY))+offset;
 }
public int getEndX() {
    return (end[0]*(width/SizeX))+offset;
}
public int getEndY() {
    return (end[1]*(height/SizeY))+offset;
}
public int getBlockW() {
    return (width/SizeX)-(2*offset);
}
public int getBlockH() {
    return (height/SizeY)-(2*offset);
}
 }
```

Comment: A suggestion might be to cut down the size of your generate() function. It's rather on the large side. By extracting small parts into their own methods, you're making the program easier to read and it's possible that you'll spot the error yourself during the process.

Comment: Its likely that your generate() function is running on an infinite loop. My magic orb says VistedCells < TotalCells never is false. Try debugging your applet and making sure it is breaking out of the loop or why it isnt.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) Re the Java Console - if there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.